# Why a client and not an app?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I searched on the play store for a stack overflow app for my android. I found out there is a client that you can use, but I was wondering why they didn't make an official app? The GUI would be much better and the buttons would look as if they belong on a mobile device. So far it looks like the desktop view squeezed onto a mobile view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is an app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en

It's not specifically or solely for stackoverflow, but stackoverflow is also in there.

Comment: But there is not one just for stack overflow

Comment: No. Imagine having to make an app for every SE site. Thats over 100 apps. So they put them all in one